# Tool Identification - screwdriver-like

Tags: tools, hand-tools, screwdriver, antique, identify-a-tool

I got this tool from my grandfather's house. It looks incomplete, like some parts are missing. The tool is simply a 1/8" steel rod about 7" long with one end flattened into a screwdriver blade, and the rod is bent into a loop about 2.5" from the blade end. See photo. Any idea what this is? Thanks[image]

Comment: The image has many pixels but poor clarity. A well-focused close-up of the flat end might show details - I can see some sort of marks on the flat part in this picture, but I can't make out what they are.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a replaceable **tine** (sometimes also called tooth) for a (tractor-drawn agricultural type) rake. Probably clamped on the "screwdriver-like" flat section. The working end would be the long straight part, and the coil facilitates spring-action.